# Vagrant update version

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I am working with Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a version of vagrant 1.8.1 .
I try to change the version to 1.8.5 with `vagrant box add --force --box-version` But it still always the same.

Does anybody know the answer.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this link: How do I upgrade vagrant to last version in ubuntu? https://superuser.com/questions/845987/how-do-i-upgrade-vagrant-to-last-version-in-ubuntu/845989